# addTA - Error in naCheck(x, n) : Series contains non-leading NAs

Tags: r, charts, quantmod, technical-indicator

I recently tried to create my own technical indicator, a simple golden cross indicator. 50 - 200 day EMA to be added to my chartSeries chart. This worked fine with the code below at first, but after the updated package of `quantmod` was released it gives me this error message:

Code (stock data is downloaded through the `getSymbols` function in `quantmod`)

```
#20dayEMA - 50dayEMA Technical indicator, Price and Volume
newEMA <- function(x){(removeNA(EMA(p[,6],n=50)-(EMA(p[,6],n=200))))
}
emaTA <- newTA(newEMA)
emaTA(col='lightgoldenrod3', 'Price')
```

Then it gives me this error message:

> Error in naCheck(x, n) : Series contains non-leading NAs

Does anyone know how to remove these non-leading NAs?

Comment: Can you show the full code, including how you download the data?

Comment: getSymbols("VELO.CO")
p<-as.xts(c(VELO.CO))                                                                                                  #20dayEMA - 50dayEMA Technical indicator, Price and Volume
newEMA <- function(x){(removeNA(EMA(p[,6],n=20)-(EMA(p[,6],n=50))))
}
emaTA <- newTA(newEMA)
emaTA(col='lightgoldenrod3', 'Price')                                                                    Thanks @jsb

Comment: @jsb The getSymbols and p<-as.xts(c(VELO.CO)) are two seperate codes. Sorry for the ugly format, still getting used to stackoverflow. Thanks a bunch in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `na.omit` and there is no need to convert to an `xts-object` as this is the default.

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("VELO.CO")
p <- na.omit(VELO.CO)
newEMA <- function(x) {
  EMA(p[,6], n = 20) - (EMA(p[,6], n = 50))
}

emaTA <- newTA(newEMA)
barChart(VELO.CO)
emaTA(col = "lightgoldenrod3", "Price")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the `quantmod` package, but I played around with your code and I think I found a working solution:

```
library("quantmod")
getSymbols("VELO.CO")
p <- as.xts(c(VELO.CO))

# remove incomplete cases
vec <- which(!complete.cases(p))  # rows 2305 2398
p2 <- p[-vec, ]

newEMA <- function(x) {
    EMA(p2[, 6], n = 20) - (EMA(p2[, 6], n = 50))
}

emaTA <- newTA(newEMA)
barChart(VELO.CO)
emaTA(col = "lightgoldenrod3", "Price")
```

Comment: This worked, thanks a bunch @jsb                                                                    What exactly does the which function do?

Comment: `which` gives the `TRUE` indices of a logical object, in this case the output vector of `complete.cases`.